# How to create a scatterplot with 1000 rows of data, indexed/plotted by one variable, with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a data set of 1000 rows and 100 columns, with numbers ordered from smallest to largest left to right (these are all dates, or years in which something has happened). I want to create a scatter plot of this numeric data with each row plotted against an ordinal index of the numbers 1-100 in ascending order. So for example the dataframe is:

```
       [1] [2] [3] [4] ... [100]
   [1] 202 216 398 401 ... 2000
   [2] 203 243 284 350 ... 1998
   [3] 211 269 299 321 ... 2000
  ...
[1000] 200 247 273 300 ... 1999
```

I'd like to index each point in every row by 1-100, so essentially plot all rows by the numbers 1-100. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm new and self-taught in R. I've tried it with ggplot and I've also tried to covert the data frame to a matrix and use matplot, but can't quite get it right. I'm shooting for the numbers 1-100 on the y axis, and the numbers 1-2000 on the x.

Here's an example of the graph I am trying to replicate, which I created in Excel (with only 250 series).

[image: Here's]

I understand this will be quite the messy graph, but I am replicating someone else's agent based model and want to compare my graph and results with their published data.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please edit your question to show the code you've tried and state exactly what is not quite right? Currently, this reads as a code-writing request, which will probably be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R almost always thinks about data in columns, not rows, and for `ggplot` you would want long-format not wide-format data.

Let's get some sample input:

```
nr = 1000
nc = 100
set.seed(47)
m = matrix(sample(1:2000, size = nr * nc, replace = TRUE), ncol = nc)

# base
plot(x = c(1,2000), y = c(1,100), type = "n")
for(i in 1:nr) points(m[i, ], 1:100, cex = 0.1, pch = 20)

# ggplot
# get data in long format
d = data.frame(x = c(t(m)), y = rep(1:100, nr))
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(shape = '.', alpha = 0.1)
```

These both look pretty bad since the fake data is just uniformly distributed, but it should give you the right idea.

Comment: You could adapt the same logic for the `ggplot` reshaping to use `matplot` as well - `matplot(t(m), 1:100, type="p", cex=0.1, pch=20, col="black")`

Comment: Thank you so much! It's those little quirks about R and understanding how it likes data that I need to learn to get better at this. I really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with 2 lines of plotting code. The first creates an empty plot with the specified axis limits. The second plots one row of your data-matrix at a time. This might not the most elegant solution, but this  will run fast enough given the size of the data:

```
# generate fake data matching your example
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=1000, ncol=100)
for(r in 1:1000) mat[r, ] <- sort(sample(0:2000, 100))

# create empty plot
plot(x=NA, y=NA, xlim=c(0,2000), ylim=c(0,100), xlab="", ylab="")

# plot your data
for(r in 1:1000) points(x=mat[r,], y=1:100, pch=20)
```